# How to make images with anchor tags stay next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am creating an explore page for my social site and I need some help. I am trying to make images and videos stay next to each other with anchor tags `<a></a>`. But whenever I do it, the images lose their `border-radius` and just appear anywhere at the top of the screen. How do I make them stay right next to each other ?
[image: How it looks without any tags inside the while loop except video or image]

---

[image: How it looks with tags other than videos or image.]

```
<div class="explore">

<?php

    // output data of each row
    while ($explore_image->fetch()) {

        if ($userLoggedIn != $added_by) {

            $parts = explode('.', $image);
            $extension = array_pop($parts);

            if($extension == 'mp4'){
                echo "<a href='#' class='explore_image'><video class='explore_image' controls>
                        <source src='$image' type='video/mp4'>
                    </video></a>";
            }
            elseif($extension == 'gif' || 'png' || 'jpg' || 'jpeg'){

                echo "<a href='#'><img src='$image' class='explore_image'></a>";
            }
            else {
                echo "";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "";
        }
    }
    
    $explore_image->close();
    $con->close();

?>
</div><br><br>

.explore {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.explore_image{

width: 40%;
flex: 1 0 20%;
margin: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to you if you stripped the PHP away as your question, from what I can tell, is more about html and css

Comment: It's all mixed into one

Comment: Yes, but only CSS related. You just set width to 40% probably thats why they look so weird. Can you copy the rendered HTML and post it?

Comment: Thats' the only code that is involved with this page @NoNickAvailable

Comment: @Dominik There's no need to strip the php. The tag Brandon used was removed in an edit I made. That will suffice. It would be relevant though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example, this might be a start for your layout. Enter fullscreen and resize the window to see the effect.

```css
.explore {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
}

.explore-item {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.explore-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="explore">

  <div class="explore-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="explore-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="explore-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="explore-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="explore-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="explore-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="explore-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="explore-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="explore-item">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="explore-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks cool but I want the images to be about 3 or 4 on a line and then break and do the same thing

Comment: To achieve this you must have the images to be about 20-25% of the width of the parent container. The example above breaks the images in the next line, because there isn't enough space.

Comment: That's better but the images have a big gap between them and if I make the padding 0 and make the margin 0 it still looks bad

Comment: The gap comes from 'flex: space around' you can remove this line and only use padding

Comment: Ok and one more thing. The images are small and when i increase the width of it, they overlap one another

Comment: Okay, thats strange. Did you give them something like 'position: absolute'?

Comment: No I haven't. Should I ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219372/discussion-between-nonickavailable-and-brandon-t).